# Java - Priority of threads methods & other various methods in main()

Tags: java, multithreading

I Have the following code:

```
 class PrintThread extends Thread
 {
 private int sleepTime;
 public PrintThread( String name )
 {
 super( name );
 sleepTime = (int) ( Math.random( ) * 15000 );
 System.err.println( "Name:"+getName( )+";sleep: " + sleepTime );
 }
public void run( )
{
try
{
  System.err.println( getName( ) + " going to sleep" );
  Thread.sleep( sleepTime );
}
catch ( InterruptedException interruptedException )
{
  System.err.println( interruptedException.toString() );
}
System.err.println( getName( ) + " done sleeping" );
}
}
public class ThreadTester
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
PrintThread thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
thread1 = new PrintThread( "thread1" );
thread2 = new PrintThread( "thread2" );
thread3 = new PrintThread( "thread3" );
thread4 = new PrintThread( "thread4" );
System.err.println( "\nStarting threads" );
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
thread4.start();
System.err.println( "Threads started\n" );
}
}
```

each time i run it, the output differs from the previous run.
for example
RUN1:

```
Name:thread1;sleep: 5608
Name:thread2;sleep: 2007
Name:thread3;sleep: 7443
Name:thread4;sleep: 1601

Starting threads
thread2 going to sleep
Threads started

thread1 going to sleep
thread4 going to sleep
thread3 going to sleep
thread4 done sleeping
thread2 done sleeping
thread1 done sleeping
thread3 done sleeping
```

RUN2:

```
Name:thread1;sleep: 2033
Name:thread2;sleep: 4896
Name:thread3;sleep: 1217
Name:thread4;sleep: 150

Starting threads
Threads started

thread2 going to sleep
thread3 going to sleep
thread1 going to sleep
thread4 going to sleep
thread4 done sleeping
thread3 done sleeping
```

why  System.err.println( "Threads started\n" );   is executed before any other thread sometimes, & sometimes after     thread1.start(); ?!
i know threads have priority issue, but that applies to threads between each other as i know!

Comment: Are you saying you see "thread 1 going to sleep" before "Starting threads"?

Comment: There's a random sleep time, so of course the output will differ.

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Indent your code properly.

Comment: If you want a specific execution order why are you using threads?

Comment: "that applies to threads between each other" - Including the thread executing your main method, which starts the other four, right?

Comment: My exact question is why System.err.println( "Threads started\n" ); is executing before threads start.. Please note that all the threads have to show the sentence "thread is going to sleep" before they actually sleep.. In another way.. Shouldn't the output be something like this: Name:thread1;sleep: 2033 Name:thread2;sleep: 4896 Name:thread3;sleep: 1217 Name:thread4;sleep: 150 Starting threads thread2 going to sleep thread3 going to sleep thread1 going to sleep thread4 going to sleep thread4 done sleeping thread3 done sleeping Threads started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a thread it could happen almost immediately, i.e. before the next line is executed, and sometimes it has a small delay which could be a couple of milli-seconds, so it will appear later in the output.

Threads take a random amount of time to actually start.